# Solr replication stopped working (replicatableGeneration)

Tags: solr, replication

I have a Solr master/slave setup using [replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication).

However this suddenly stopped working, I'm not sure what happened.

When I look at `/replication?command=details` on the master server, I see the following:

```
...
<str name="isMaster">true</str>
<str name="isSlave">false</str>
<long name="indexVersion">1323950636535</long>
<long name="generation">16</long>
<lst name="master">
  <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>
  <arr name="replicateAfter">
    <str>optimize</str>
    <str>startup</str>
  </arr>
  <str name="replicationEnabled">true</str>
  <long name="replicatableIndexVersion">1323950636529</long>
  <long name="replicatableGeneration">14</long>
</lst>
...
```

Note the difference in the `generation` and the `replicatableGeneration`.

The slave is stuck at generation 14.
When I update the master its generation becomes 17, while the replicatableGeneration stays at 14.

Why would these two differ, and how can I get replicatableGeneration to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check when replication can/should occur (in index settings), maybe you add/deleted something to the index and didn't committed changes, or you committed them, but didn't optimized
- Start replication by hand and trace logs for errors

If replication failed for some reason ie. lack of space on hdd or java error, it's like it never happen - generation will not change.
If any of above method failed: stop slave, remove replicated index (on slave), start slave again and let it work.
All of above happen to me at some point of working with Solr :)

Comment: Well, you were right. I committed something to the index, but didn't optimize. And as replication was set to only work after optimization, it stayed on the old generation. It's always something simple like that...

Comment: @Fuxi I have same problem and solr replica goes in recovery mode at some time. its getting back again after some time so any way to find out why its getting in recovery mode. I mean any monitor tools/ we can enable some specif logs to find out the reason. Would be great if you can provide some details for the same.

Comment: I'm sorry @Ranjitsinh but I can't help with that, I have not worked with Solr for years now.